# Vue3 bundling and debugger not working issue

Tags: webpack, vuejs3

I have a Vue3 project, written in VSCode. Up until today I have not experienced any issue with viewing the project in the browser with:

```
npm run serve
```

and adding break points:

```
debugger
```

to cause the code to pause in the inspector as you would expect.

However, something has changed and code not longer pauses when a debugger line is reached. I am unsure what might have caused this. For example, if I add:

```
created() {
    console.log('Reached here');
    debugger;
}
```

to a component, 'Reached here' is seen in the console but the debugger is ignored.

Also, viewing the component in the Source window has changed. The code is now found in the webpack-internal .... babel-loader/lib folder.

[image]

I realise that this is a very broad question, but if there are any pointers as to why I am seeing this behaviour I would be very grateful.